# Passing data between non-adjacent activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Let's say I have 3 activities, called A, B and C which are shown in sequence to the user. (A -> B-> C)
There's an imageCache in activity A that needs to be accessed by activity C. 
Considering that image caches can be a few megabytes in size, is it OK to pass the cache from A -> B -> C using intents?

I've also read about global singleton contexts.. is this the right way to go?

Comment: Global single instance of image cache is right way to go.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Either ways it will work but the first A > B > C is a waste of resources and logically not correct. So I would use the second option, a global single instance (use a singleton pattern) to be used whenever you need it in your application.